# How to find customer with orders greater than X from single table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find, from within a single table, customer names with orders greater than $2000 ?

```
Customer : 
custName custOrderVal
A        100 
B        200
A        900
C        2400
A        1100
B        8000
```

`select cust.custName from customer cust where cust.custOrderVal > 2000;` will not show the correct data. Can someone please guide me on this ?

Comment: What data are you getting? Your query looks correct.

Comment: What is your desired output add in your question

Comment: What's the data type of `custOrderVal`?

Comment: is it the sum of orders you want to filter, or single orders?

Comment: My query is just returning C and B (for their individual entries of 2400 and 8000), where as A also has a total order greater than 2000.

Comment: @BhupeshC Yes, sum of all orders by the customers

Comment: You need to use `GROUP BY` to get the `SUM` per customer and then use `HAVING` to limit the result (just like a `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (custName VARCHAR(10),custOrderVal INT)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('A',100), ('B',200),('A',900),('C',2400),
('A',1100),('B',8000),('D',1000),('F',500)

SELECT  CustName
FROM @t
GROUP BY CustName
HAVING SUM(custOrderVal) > 2000
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╗
║ CustName ║
╠══════════╣
║ A        ║
║ B        ║
║ C        ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: are you sure, if you dont use distinct, it will give duplicates?

Comment: -1 : `DISTINCT CustName` and `GROUP BY CustName` don't go together: Either `DISTINCT` it is optimized away, or it messes up the query plan.

Answer (score 2):

By using `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
SELECT custName
FROM Customer
GROUP BY custName
HAVING SUM(custOrderVal) > 2000
```

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get the `SUM` per customer and then use `HAVING` to limit the result (just like a `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  custName,
  SUM(custOrderVal) AS custOrderSum
FROM Customer
GROUP BY custName
HAVING custOrderSum>2000
```

Comment: Ahh.. Dang ! The Sum function, Group By and Having - it was ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to filter Grouped Totals, you use `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT custName
FROM Customer
GROUP BY custName
HAVING SUM(custOrderVal) > 2000
```